# Merging pandas dataframes on 2 columns but in either order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

## The problem:

I've got a situation with 2 dataframes:

```
test1 = pd.DataFrame({'id_A':['Ben', 'Julie', 'Jack', 'Jack'],
                  'id_B':['Julie', 'Ben', 'Nina', 'Julie']})

test2 = pd.DataFrame({'id_a':['Ben', 'Ben', 'Ben', 'Julie', 'Julie', 'Nina'],
                      'id_b':['Julie', 'Nina', 'Jack', 'Nina', 'Jack', 'Jack'],
                      'value':[1,1,0,0,1,0]})

>>> test1
    id_A   id_B
0    Ben  Julie
1  Julie    Ben
2   Jack   Nina
3   Jack  Julie

>>> test2
    id_a   id_b  value
0    Ben  Julie      1
1    Ben   Nina      1
2    Ben   Jack      0
3  Julie   Nina      0
4  Julie   Jack      1
5   Nina   Jack      0
```

What I'd like to do is merge `test2` with `test1` where `id_A == id_a` and `id_B == id_b` **OR** where `id_A == id_b` and `id_B == id_a`, resulting in the following dataframe:

```
>>> final_df
    id_A   id_B  value
0    Ben  Julie      1
1  Julie    Ben      1
2   Jack   Nina      0
3   Jack  Julie      1
```

## Current Solution:

My solution works but seems messy, and I'd like to see if I'm overlooking some more clever way to do things. It involves concatenating `test2` with itself, but reversing the 2 columns of interest (`id_a` becomes `id_b` and vice-versa), and then merging from there.

```
test3 = pd.concat([test2, test2.rename(columns = {'id_a':'id_b', 'id_b':'id_a'})])

final_df = (test1.merge(test3, left_on = ['id_A', 'id_B'],
                        right_on = ['id_a', 'id_b'])
            .drop(['id_a', 'id_b'], axis=1))
```

## Question:

Does anyone know a neater way to do this? I feel like I'm probably overlooking some amazing pandorable way of doing things.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `frozenset`

```
test1.assign(
    value=test1.apply(frozenset, 1).map({frozenset(a): b for *a, b in test2.values}))

    id_A   id_B  value
0    Ben  Julie      1
1  Julie    Ben      1
2   Jack   Nina      0
3   Jack  Julie      1
```

---

Less cute, more robust.  Remove what you need to afterwards.

```
t1 = test1.assign(ref=list(map(frozenset, zip(test1.id_A, test1.id_B))))
t2 = test2.assign(ref=list(map(frozenset, zip(test2.id_a, test2.id_b))))

t1.merge(t2, on='ref')

    id_A   id_B            ref   id_a   id_b  value
0    Ben  Julie   (Julie, Ben)    Ben  Julie      1
1  Julie    Ben   (Julie, Ben)    Ben  Julie      1
2   Jack   Nina   (Jack, Nina)   Nina   Jack      0
3   Jack  Julie  (Jack, Julie)  Julie   Jack      1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try `np.sort`

```
test1.assign(key=pd.DataFrame(np.sort(test1.values,axis=1)).sum(1)).merge(test2.assign(key=pd.DataFrame(np.sort(test2[['id_a','id_b']].values,axis=1)).sum(1))).drop('key',1)
Out[188]: 
    id_A   id_B   id_a   id_b  value
0    Ben  Julie    Ben  Julie      1
1  Julie    Ben    Ben  Julie      1
2   Jack   Nina   Nina   Jack      0
3   Jack  Julie  Julie   Jack      1
```

Comment: That's pretty clever! I guess there's no magic `pandas` function for what I'm trying to do :(

Comment: @sacul I do not think pandas can do this, since it need reconstruct the dataframe(columns side ) for merge purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You could do two inner joins, then concatenate and de-duplicate, something like:

```
merge_1 = test1.merge(test2, left_on = ['id_A', 'id_B'], right_on= ['id_a', 'id_b'])
merge_2 = test1.merge(test2, left_on = ['id_A', 'id_B'], right_on= ['id_b', 'id_a'])
final_df = pd.concat([merge_1, merge_2]).drop_duplicates()
```

Or you could do an outer join and compute the condition manually:

```
final_df = test1.merge(test2, how='outer')
final_df = final_df[((final_df.id_A == final_df.id_a) &
                     (final_df.id_B == final_df.id_b)) |
                    ((final_df.id_A == final_df.id_b) &
                     (final_df.id_B == final_df.id_a))]
```

Or you could create a joined key that's always in a known order:

```
test1['join_key'] = test1.apply(lambda row: tuple(sorted(row[['id_A', 'id_B']])), axis=1)
test2['join_key'] = test2.apply(lambda row: tuple(sorted(row[['id_a', 'id_b']])), axis=1)
final_df = test1.merge(test2, on='join_key').drop('join_key')
```

Comment: Yeah, the two merges method was one of my first attempts, it works well too. Thanks for the options!